# How to save String date format like 'yyyy-MM-dd' as a Date object in mongodb using mule 4?

Tags: dataweave, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

Receiving payload contains date as String with format of `yyyy-MM-dd`, by using transform component I converted like `as Date {class: "java.time.LocalDate"}` in mule 4.

But when inserting document in mongodb, this date is saving as String object instead of LocalDate object.

How to store the string date format like `yyyy-MM-dd` as `Date` Object in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am a newbie when it comes to MongoDB, JSON does not support a `date` type.  From the spec:
`A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.`

https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf, Page 2, Section 5.

You probably will have to split the date into its constituents parts inside a JSON object yourself or use some MongoDB native feature to store it as a MongoDB date.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#date_decomposition

PS: If you provide more details of your mule 4 app I may be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Based on document provide in MongoDB , explored on it. I think  Its not possible to convert as Date object. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

Comment: What about this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/#date

Comment: Please  check on this document: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date. It is saying that BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)